# react-native auth0 Missing NativeModule

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, auth0

I'm currently working on a project with react native that includes Auth0 for login purposes.
When I tried to configure the package it gave me this error:

```
Error: Missing NativeModule. Please make sure you run `react-native link react-native-auth0`
    at Agent.newTransaction (agent.js:33)
    at WebAuth.authorize (index.js:55)
    at App (App.js:23)
    at instantiate (createClassProxy.js:94)
    at new App (eval at proxyClass (createClassProxy.js:112), <anonymous>:4:17)
    at constructClassInstance (ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8871)
    at updateClassComponent (ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11400)
    at beginWork (ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12588)
    at performUnitOfWork (ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15852)
    at workLoop (ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15892)
```

I thought that it was due to an error in linking the module, so I did it manually but nothing changes.

Comment: did u run again ?

Comment: obviously I did it

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules folder and run `npm install` again.

Comment: https://community.auth0.com/t/react-native-quick-start-not-working/34039

Answer (score 1):

Probably, I am late. But posting it for future reference. React Native CLI provides auto-linking functionality which replaces the command `react-native link`.

For IOS, just run

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md#autolinking